# Unable to add tracks to already running Tweetinvi Filtered Stream

Tags: c#, streaming, tweetinvi

I am using Tweetinvi Twitter API Wrapper to track multiple users' stream. As per requirement I have to add more tracks (@mentions) to the stream already listening.

The code I am using to stop an already running filtered stream and then resuming it back with new track added is as follows (as suggested in Tweetinvi official forum reference [here](http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/discussions/541286))

```
// first time starting filtered stream in static void main()
filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAnyCondition();

// then in another static method
filteredStream.StopStream();
filteredStream.AddTrack("@newmention");
filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAnyCondition();
```

// OR also tried using *ResumeStream* instead of *StartStreamMatchingAnyCondition* above:

```
filteredStream.ResumeStream();
```

But as soon as the last line executes, it just STOPS tracking any tweets from any of already tracked users (@mentions). And after some time, the stream automatically ended up with following error:

> Value can not be Null. Parameter name: source